# InvalidRegistration for FCM in php?

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving an [InvalidRegistration] error in `send_fcm` message

Following is the code that I have used:

```
<?php 
define("GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY", "AAAAgTwiaRM:APA91bFyOiLtJKim7FIKpW...Mk6rR4xlTNDr1Ia0sJmerecuD6U1c6xsQh8PZdKz");
function send_fcm($message, $id) {
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$headers = array (
    'Authorization: key='.GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$fields = array (
    'data' => array ("message" => $message),
    'notification' => array ("body" => $message)
);
if(is_array($id)) {
    $fields['registration_ids'] = $id;
} else {
    $fields['to'] = $id;
}
$fields['priority'] = "high";
$fields = json_encode ($fields);
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close ( $ch );

return $result;
}
$message_status= send_fcm("test", "sketch_up");

echo $message_status;
?>
```

After I execute the above code, I find the error as mentioned below

```
{"multicast_id":7765951050747928269,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

What could be the root cause - how may I fix?

Comment: I solved it ,  i didn't  add a topic...

Comment: Please post your solution and mark it as the answer so that others can benefit as well

Comment: if you want send message by topic you have to add /topics/sketch_up

Comment: pls provide the code i am also stucked on this @PhilipYoon